# Unable to get concat value of object on page from redux store in React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, reducers

I am not able to update my comment on the page.

After submiting it is showing comment object in the console log but not on the page [Console log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN87R.png)

here is my comment.js

```js
import {COMMENTS} from '../shared/comments';
import * as ActionType from './ActionTypes';

export const Comments=(state=COMMENTS ,action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case ActionType.ADD_COMMENT:
            var comment = action.payload;
            comment.id = state.length;
            comment.date = new Date().toISOString();
            console.log("Comment: ", comment);
            return state.concat(comment);
        
        default:
            return state;
    };
}
```

here in my store

```js
import {createStore, combineReducers} from 'redux';
import {Dishes} from './dishes';
import {Comments} from './comments';
import {Leaders} from './leaders';
import {Promotions} from './promotions';

export const ConfigureStore=() =>{
    const store=createStore(
       combineReducers({
            dishes:Dishes,
            comments:Comments,
            leaders:Leaders,
            promotions:Promotions
       })
    );

    return store;
};
```

here is my action creator

```js
import * as ActionTypes from './ActionTypes';

export const addComment=(dishID,rating,author,comment) => ({
    type:ActionTypes.ADD_COMMENT,
    payload:{
        dishID:dishID,
        rating:rating,
        author:author,
        comment:comment,
    }
});
```

here is my App.js

```js
import React from 'react';  
import Main from './components/MainComponent';
import './App.css';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {ConfigureStore} from './redux/configureStore';

const store=ConfigureStore();

class App extends React.Component {
  render()
  {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Main/>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  } 
}

export default App;
```

here is my MainComponent.js

```js
import React from 'react';  
import Menu from './MenuComponent';
import DishDetail from './DishdetailComponent';
import Home from './HomeComponent';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';
import Footer from './FooterComponent';
import Contact from './ContactComponent';
import About from './AboutComponent';
import {Switch , Route , Redirect,withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {addComment} from '../redux/ActionCreators'

const mapStateToProps=state =>{
  return{
    dishes:state.dishes,
    leaders:state.leaders,
    comments:state.comments,
    promotions:state.promotions
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  addComment:(dishId,rating,author,comment) => dispatch(addComment(dishId,rating,author,comment))
});

class Main extends React.Component {
  
  render()
  {
    const HomePage=() => {
      return(<Home dish={this.props.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.featured)[0]}
       leader={this.props.leaders.filter((leader) => leader.featured)[0]}
       promotion={this.props.promotions.filter((promo) => promo.featured)[0]} />);
    }

    const DishWithId=({match}) => {
      return(
        <DishDetail dish={this.props.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === parseInt(match.params.dishId,10))[0]}
         comments={this.props.comments.filter(comment => comment.dishId === parseInt(match.params.dishId,10))}
         addComment={this.props.addComment} />
      );
    };
    
    return (
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/home" component={HomePage}/>
          <Route exact path="/aboutus" component={() => <About leaders={this.props.leaders}/>}/>
          <Route exact path="/menu" component={() => <Menu dishes={this.props.dishes}/>} />
          <Route path="/menu/:dishId" component={DishWithId} />
          <Route exact path="/contactus" component={() => <Contact/>}/>
          <Redirect to="/home"/>
        </Switch>
        <Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(Main));
```

here is my dishdetail.js component

```js
import React from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import { Card, CardImg, CardBody, CardTitle, CardText ,Breadcrumb ,BreadcrumbItem ,Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, Label,Row} from 'reactstrap';
import { LocalForm, Control,Errors } from 'react-redux-form';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const maxLength=(len) => (val) => !(val) || (val.length <= len);
const minLength=(len) => (val) => (val) && (val.length >= len);

class CommentForm extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state={
            isModalOpen:false
        };
        this.toggleModal=this.toggleModal.bind(this);
        this.handelSubmit=this.handelSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    toggleModal()
    {
        this.setState({
            isModalOpen: !this.state.isModalOpen
        });
    }

    handelSubmit(values)
    {
        this.props.addComment(this.props.dishId,values.rating,values.author,values.comment);
        this.toggleModal();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <Button outline onClick={this.toggleModal}><span className="fa fa-pencil"></span>{' '}Submit Comment</Button>
            

                {/*--Modal For Comment--*/}

                <Modal id="commentModal" isOpen={this.state.isModalOpen} toggle={this.toggleModal}>
                    <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggleModal}>Submit Comment</ModalHeader>
                    <ModalBody>
                        <LocalForm onSubmit={(values) => this.handelSubmit(values)} >
                            <Row className="form-row mt-2">
                                <Label htmlFor="rating">Rating</Label>
                                <Control.select model=".rating"
                                id="rating"
                                name="rating"
                                className="form-control"
                                >
                                    <option>1</option>
                                    <option>2</option>
                                    <option>3</option>
                                    <option>4</option>
                                    <option>5</option>
                                </Control.select>
                            </Row>
                            <Row className="form-row mt-2">
                                <Label htmlFor="author">Your Name</Label>
                                <Control.text model=".author"
                                id="author"
                                name="author"
                                className="form-control"
                                placeholder="Your Name"
                                validators={{
                                    minLength:minLength(3),
                                    maxLength:maxLength(15)
                                }}
                                />
                                <Errors 
                                className="text-danger"
                                model=".author"
                                show="touched"
                                messages={{
                                    minLength:'Must be greater than 2 characters',
                                    maxLength:'Must be 15 characters or less'
                                }}/>
                            </Row>
                            <Row className="form-row mt-2">
                                <Label htmlFor="comment">Comment</Label>
                                <Control.textarea model=".comment"
                                rows="6"
                                id="comment"
                                name="comment"
                                className="form-control"
                                />
                            </Row>
                            <Row className="form-row mt-2">
                                <Button type="submit" color="primary" >Submit</Button>
                            </Row>
                        </LocalForm>
                    </ModalBody>
                </Modal>

            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}


    function RenderDish({dish})
    {
        return(
            <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                <Card>
                    <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                    <CardBody>
                        <CardTitle><strong>{dish.name}</strong></CardTitle>
                        <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
                    </CardBody>
                </Card>
            </div>
        );
    }

    function RenderComments({comments,dishId,addComment})
    {
        if(comments!=null)
        {   
            return(
                <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
                    <h4>comments</h4>
                    <ul className="list-unstyled">
                        {comments.map(comment => {
                            return(
                            <li  key={comment.id}>
                                <p>{comment.comment}</p>
                                <p>--{comment.author} ,{new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US',{year:'numeric',month:'short',day:'2-digit'}).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.date)))}</p>
                            </li>
                            );
                        })}
                    </ul>
                    <CommentForm dishId={dishId} addComment={addComment}/>
                </div>
            );
        }
        else{
            return <div></div>
        }      
    }
    function DishDetail(props)
    {
        if(props.dish!=null)
        { 
            return(
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <Breadcrumb >
                            <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/home">Home</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
                            <BreadcrumbItem><Link to="/menu">Menu</Link></BreadcrumbItem>
                            <BreadcrumbItem>{props.dish.name}</BreadcrumbItem>
                        </Breadcrumb>
                        <div className="col-12">
                            <h3>{props.dish.name}</h3>
                            <hr/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <RenderDish dish={props.dish}/>
                        <RenderComments comments={props.comments} dishId={props.dish.id} addComment={props.addComment}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );           
        }
        else
        {
            return(
                <div></div>
            );
        }
    }

export default DishDetail;
```

please help !!

Comment: You reducer seems to look fine.

Comment: Do 1 thing
https://redux.js.org/api/store/#subscribelistener
use subscribe and getState() to see if the store actually has updated.
Also it'd be much easier if the example is created in a codesandbox..

Comment: Also in your mainComponent you're declaring the component inside a render.

Comment: @Pavan i am new to react still learning so i don't know how to use subscribe and get state but i am getting this error in console after submit the form                                        
 react_devtools_backend.js:6 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See for details.

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps.

Comment: @Pavan 
* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: Control, Form

Comment: Based on the code you pasted here there's no componentWillreceiveProps. So I don't think this warning has got anything to do with your code.

Comment: @Pavan i tried using subscription and getState and yes store is updating . After submit the getstate array length increased by 1 and new comment was in array

Comment: Naman can you please create a codesandbox from this code.
There seem to be lot of problems with the way you've done JSX.
Your component declaration needs be corrected.

Comment: @Pavan here is link to my sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-haze-kh4k6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-water-ht4c9?file=/src/redux/ActionCreators.js
Hey you were using the wrong key for the dishId in your action.
Also I've updated some code i.e moved some component declarations out of the render method.

Comment: @Pavan thanks a lot for your help man i wasted a whole day trying to correct this. Thanks a lot !